# Is it possible to use emmet.io autocomplete with the nitrous.io IDE

Tags: ide, emmet, nitrousio

I would like to use nitrous.io for development, but its such a pain to write everything out by hand. is there a way i could use emmet.io with nitrous for autocomplete

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nitrous doesn't offer autocomplete in the IDE text editor, but you could utilize Vim in the terminal and install the [emmet-vim plugin](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim).

Answer (score 0):

Nitrous now provides an Atom plug-in (called Nitrogen) that allows you to sync your files in Atom, and then you can use emmet plug-in in Atom.

For more information, see:

https://community.nitrous.io/docs/using-the-nitrogen-atom-plugin